# Dialog Box closes in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a **Update Button** by clicking on which data loads in background.

When the data loads I am displaying **AlertDialog** which closes automatically when the data gets loaded.

However while the data is loading and if the user clicks somewhere else on screen the Dialog Box closes which is undesirable.

The question is **How can I prevent DialogBox to close?**

```
 Future<void> _loadingDialog(String title) async {
 return showDialog(
   context: context,
   barrierDismissible: true,
   builder: (context) {
     return AlertDialog(
       title: Text(title),
       content: LinearProgressIndicator(
         backgroundColor: colorPrimaryLight,
         valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(colorPrimaryDark),
       ),
     );
   },
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it was simple I just had to set

```
barrierDismissible: false,
```